# Domain Security Group based Windows authentication

Tags: asp.net, windows-authentication, active-directory-group

I am trying to authenticate a user against our local Active Directory. All users who are allowed access to the site are part of a specific Security Group in AD.

Our web config looks like this:

```
    <authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="false"/>
    <authorization>
      <allow roles="DOMAIN\ALLOWEDUSERS"/>
      <deny users="*"/>
    </authorization>
    <httpRuntime enableVersionHeader="false" />
```

With this configuration the browser displays the HTTP Error 401.1

If you have any suggestion on what I am missing, that would be a great help. If you need more information just ask.

Comment: Which roleManager are you using? Have you tried `<deny users="?"/>
`

Comment: What's the setup in IIS on your Virtual Directory? Be sure to disable anonymous access and enable Windows Authentication. You don't say what version you use but it's very similar across most versions. See http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/524404dc-8586-46b0-89ac-0f5db6d33c9c.mspx?mfr=true